# Format excel cells based on other cells range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with many rows and columns.

I need to format a certain range of cells in column based by a range made by three cells

For instance let's say I have A value of 100 in A1, then I have two limits, I have lower limit (-3) in cell B1 and upper limit (4) in C1

Then I select the range of cells I want to change color and apply "Format only cells that contains" rule, first I use "between =B1+C1 and = B1 + C1" - color green then "not between =B1+C1 and = B1 + C1" - color red

The problem appears when I want to copy to rows below, even if I did not block any cell, I can't manage to copy the formatting to rows below, I tried all paste special options, but the values remain related to A1, B1 and C1, they don't change to A2, B2, C2 and so on.

Any idea on which I'm doing wrong?

Maybe should use a macro for it, I don't know VBA but with guide I can manage.

Thank you.

Edit:
Thank you for your code,

I want to edit it so it I would need it to start from row 3, and also to take in account C + E as low value and C + D as upper value, then change color to cells in range G to V.

I tried to edit the code, but I'm not sure how to so, below is what I tried to modify
For i = 3 To Lastrow

```
If ws1.Cells(i, "G:V") >= ws1.Cells(i, "C" + "E") And ws1.Cells(i, "D:V") <= ws1.Cells(i, "C" + "D") Then
    ws1.Cells(i, "A").Interior.color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'If Value in Column A is in betwen (color green)
Else
    ws1.Cells(i, "A").Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'If Value in Column A is not in betwen (color red)
End If
```

Comment: maybe this can help solve your problem? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-conditional-formatting-to-other-cells-306efe99-f1d5-4a1f-851b-c9695ab05001

Comment: I tried that already, the problem is that the cell remains A1, B1, C1, whatever reference I apply to that formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this with VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow

    If ws1.Cells(i, "A") > ws1.Cells(i, "B") And ws1.Cells(i, "A") < ws1.Cells(i, "C") Then
        ws1.Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'If Value in Column A is in betwen (color green)
    Else
        ws1.Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'If Value in Column A is not in betwen (color red)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To Lastrow ' Start at row 3

LowerLimit = ws1.Cells(i, "C") + ws1.Cells(i, "E") ' Low Value
UpperLimt = ws1.Cells(i, "C") + ws1.Cells(i, "D") ' Upper Value

    For c = 7 To 22 ' From column G to column V

            If ws1.Cells(i, c) >= LowerLimit And ws1.Cells(i, c) <= UpperLimt Then
                ws1.Cells(i, c).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'If Value is in betwen (color green)
            Else
                ws1.Cells(i, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'If Value is not in betwen (color red)
            End If

    Next c

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: No, I need it to start from row 3, and to take in account C + E as low value and C + D as upper value, then change color to cells in range G to V. It should not take in account cell A

Comment: One thing you wnat to do the Sum of the range G to V and compare it to Low value and Upper Value?

Comment: No, I have different values in range G to V, I just want to compare each cell value with Lower and Upper, not compute the sum of range G to V. So, if C3+E3 < G3 < C3+ D3 this should be green, else red. Then check H3, I3...and so on. Afterwards go to row 4, 5...etc. Thank you.